# issues to upload 5.5inch screen in iTunes connect to publish app

Tags: app-store-connect

We are having issues uploading the screenshots for the iPhone 5.5-Inch display (can’t “choose file”), even though we have screenshots 1242x2208.
There is no option shown to add iPhone 5.5-Inch display to add in iTunes connect to publish the app.

[image]

And this app is available in two languages -- English and chinese to upload screen shot. When we select chinese option to upload screen, there is no option to add for 5.5 inch display.

Comment: What happens if you click on the "Media Manager"? Apple updated iTunes Connect recently and introduced the "Media Manager" to upload screenshot more "simply". https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/305/

Answer (score 1):

When I update the version of my App, also encountered the same situation. After trying various methods, the solution is found.

1. upload a screenshot of the non-primary language,
   [image]
2. change the primary language,
   [image]
3. modify the non-primary language screenshot,
4. change back the primary language.

Yeah Succeed!!!

Comment: There's something wrong with the scripts in there http://prntscr.com/c502bp

But this workaround actually works. Thanks!